# In UNO with card stacking rules, can you stack the opponents final card?

Tags: house-rules, uno

While playing UNO in the end only two players were left.
Player 1 had five cards and player 2 had two cards (both of them a 'Draw 2').

- Player 2 puts down the first 'Draw 2' card, and calls UNO.
- Player 1 stacks on it a 'Draw 2' card.
- Player 2 puts down his last card that is a 'Draw 2'.
- Player 1 again stacks on it a 'Draw 2' card.

Does that last 'Draw 2' apply to player 2 or has he won?

Answer (score 4):

We have played with this house rule in our gaming group before and we resolved it in the same way we resolve MTG (Magic the Gathering) chains and that is the action must resolve upon the final valid play. So, if you are playing with the chain draw 2 house rule, in your scenario where there are two players remaining, the player who is unable to add another draw 2 into the chain is the one who gets stuck drawing as many cards as are in the stack.

If this results in one of the two players going out, that player wins. Otherwise, they draw more cards and the game continues.

The "As soon as one player goes out" rule as it was originally written for Uno did not take into effect this "chain stacking" house rule. In order to be the most correct, it must be interpreted to mean "As soon as one player goes out at the end of a play". In this case, the draw 2 chain is considered a single play as the draw 2 chain only stops (resolves) on the player that cannot place a draw 2 on the stack.

As a final note, we ultimately did away with Chain draw 2 combinations because of this exact argument we would have every time a new player arrived. If two players remain, player one has 5 cards, player two has 2 cards, player two gives player one a Draw 2, then player one draws 2 cards, then plays a Draw 2 back on Player two. No stacking or chaining is in effect, so Player two now has 3 cards and Player one has 6, and the game continues.

Comment: From what you describe with Magic I'm not sure if you mean people keep having a chance to add to the stack, or if you mean you fully resolve the stack before players lose. The second would be a house rule, since players lose when state-based actions are checked, which is in between resolving items on the stack.

Comment: What I was trying to describe is that if nobody has drawn any cards, the card is still "in play" waiting to resolve similar to the way instants work in MTG. So there is a big stack of draw 2 cards waiting to be applied to a single player. I apologize if there was confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are playing with (at least) two house rules that drastically change the game your question could be answered many ways. However since in the basic rules the game ends as soon as someone is out of cards I would say that in this case as soon as a player plays the last card they are removed from the game. Since there was only two players left that would end the game completely.

Comment: Out of interest, which two house rules? I can see one: Allowing a draw2 to be placed on a draw2 to "pass it along".

Comment: @Pod Chain draw two is a house rule as in the official rules your turn ends when a draw two card is played on you. Also as I mentioned the game ends when the first player runs out of cards.

Answer (score -3):

As per the rules, the game would end when the cards count turns to be zero. But when the opponent places a draw-2 card, player 2 needs to stack up again.

Comment: No, because the official rules do not allow the second player to place a draw 2 card.

Comment: When a draw 2 card is placed by player 1, player 2 has an equal chance of placing a draw 2 card of any color.

Comment: Why not? When a player places draw 2 card, the opponent has an equal chance of placing another draw 2 card.

Comment: No, they don't. As JoeW has pointed out in this answer, the option for player 2 to respond with a Draw 2 is a house rule. **It is not in the official rules**.